# PHP - Require not loading page

Tags: php, require

When I try to require a file into my HTML, my web page isn't loading anymore.

The file I want to require is empty so it isn't a scripting error.

```
require_once('required/dbClass.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = 'Test User';
$testing=true;
```

This code above is working just fine and my page is loading as it is supposed to.

But when I try the next code, my page isn't loading anymore

```
require 'config.php';
require_once('required/dbClass.php');
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = 'Test User';
$testing=true;
```

I don't know what's wrong, I've tried getting an error with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` but that doesn't display anything.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You're sure `config.php` is available to your script?

Comment: Have you check in your apache error log ?

Comment: My config.php wasn't available, it was in a different directory, didn't notice at the time. Thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Config.php was in a different directory